# Need correction in converting UImage to 2D Array and vice versa

Tags: ios, image-processing, core-graphics

I am trying to make a 2D pixel array from UIImage and after making that array, I am converting it back to UIImage to see if the 2D Pixel array data is correct.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZ0Nb.png  this link has two images. Bottom one is obtained after converting back pixel data to UIImage. Top One is the original image. Boths looks exactly similar, however when you zoom in, you will see that the pixels that should be on the last column of the image are being shown on the first column, but rest of the data is accurate.

[image]
   // image obtained from 2D pixel array(first column data inaccurate)

[image]
   // Actual Image

Below is the code that I have used to convert UIImage to pixels and vice versa. I could find out what I am doing wrong. Please help me to fix this issue.

//Code to covert UIimage to two dimensional pixel matrix

```
   CGImageRef inImage = sourceImage.CGImage;
   GContextRef cgctx = [self createARGBBitmapContextFromImage:inImage];

//if (cgctx == NULL) { return nil; /* error */ }
    size_t w = CGImageGetWidth(inImage);
    size_t h = CGImageGetHeight(inImage);
    CGRect rect = {{0,0},{w,h}}; 
    unsigned char* data = CGBitmapContextGetData (cgctx);   
    if (data != NULL) {
    // separate out the rgb values of each pixel in each matrix
    for(int y=0;y<h;y++)
    {
        for(int x=0;x<w;x++)
        {
            int offset = 4*((w*y)+x);
            int alpha =  data[offset]; 
            int red = data[offset+1]; 
            int green = data[offset+2]; 
            int blue = data[offset+3]; 

            sourceRedMatrix[x][y] = red;
            sourceGreenMatrix[x][y] = green;
            sourceBlueMatrix[x][y] = blue;
           // sourceAlphaMatrix[x][y] = alpha;
        }
    }
    CGContextRelease(cgctx); 
 if (data) 
{
    free(data);
}
```

//Code to get Back UIImage from two dimensional pixel matrix

```
for(int y=0;y<h;y++)
{
    for(int x=0;x<w;x++)
    {
         redSourceColor = sourceRedMatrix[x][y];
            greenSourceColor = sourceGreenMatrix[x][y];
            blueSourceColor = sourceBlueMatrix[x][y];                
            rawDataSource[byteIndex] = (char) (255);   // alpha =255, deliberately set
        rawDataSource[byteIndex+1] = (char) (redSourceColor);
        rawDataSource[byteIndex+2] = (char) (greenSourceColor);
        rawDataSource[byteIndex+3] = (char) (blueSourceColor);
        byteIndexSource += 4;
    }
 }CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData,w, h, 8, 4 * w, CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
  inImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage (ctx);
UIImage* updatedSourceImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:inImage];  
imageView.image = updatedSourceImage;
free(rawData);
free(sourceRedMatrix);*
```